# Using a RegEx to replace the single backslash with a double blackslash in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I need your help.

How can I convert the following string from:

var x = "A:\V10\db\"

to:

var x = "A:\\V10\\db\\"

Note that the double quotes also form part of the string.

I've tried the following with no sucess:

```
function test() {

var dbPath  =   "A:\V10\db"

dbPath = dbPath.replace(/\\/g, dbPath)

alert(dbPath)

}
```

Comment: That first statement is invalid, but guess it is for illustration and not example code?

Comment: I've fixed it, I realized that my current example didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslash is an [escape character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings), ([link two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yfce773%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)). If you use it you have to escape it as well.

Example:

```
var x = "foo\"bar"; // Here we escape double-quote as the string is enclosed by "
var x = 'foo\'bar'; // Same thing with '
```

The examples result in the literal strings

```
foo"bar
foo'bar
```

If you want to use a backslash in a string you will have to either escape them or use e.g hex notation. Example:

```
var x = "foo\\bar";    // Escaping backslash.
var x = "foo\x5cbar";  // Using hex escape sequence.
```

The examples both result in the literal string:

```
foo\bar
```

Now to get two back-slash characters you have escape both giving us four per two.

```
var x = "foo\\\\bar";
var x = "foo\x5c\x5cbar";
```

The examples both result in the literal string:

```
foo\\bar
```

Now, after that is out of the way, the replacement of single back-slash with double should be trivial:

```
x = x.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
    |          |  |    |
    |          |  |    +----- With two back-slashes. (both escaped.)
    |          |  +---------- Replace globally (all).
    |          +------------- Replace single backslash (and as usual escape it)
    +------------------------ The string variable
```

---

#### Other escape sequences:

Backslash is not only used to escape quotes or backslash, but also to represent special control characters and escape sequences – ref. links at top. Besides the already used `\xNN` we have for example:

```
\n  Newline
\t  Tab
```

So given this statement:

```
var x = "Some\nDay\tWe are\ngone.";
```

Result in the string:

```
Some<NEW LINE>
Day<TAB>We are<NEW LINE>
gone
```